# Points do not appear in my uPlot chart (chart appears with no problem)

Tags: javascript, flask, charts, uplot

I have created a **Flask**proyect to show in real time some metrics from the computer. First I used chart.js and everything works fine. Here is what I achived with using **chart.js**:
[image: chart.js]

This library is not as fast as I need, so after investigating i found that I could use either **uPlot** or **WebGL-plot**.

I'm trying using [uPlot](https://github.com/leeoniya/uPlot).

This is what I've done so far. First of all this is the structure my project has:

```
-FLASK_UPLOT/
   - .venv/
   - static/
      - css/
         - base.css
         - index.css
         - uPlot.min.css
      - scripts/
         - script_cpu.js
         - script_drive.js
         - script_ram.js
         - script_temp.js
         - uPlot.iife.js
         - uPlot.iife.min.js
   - templates/
      - base.html
      - index.html
   - app.py
```

`app.py` here I obtain the data I need to plot later (saved in **json**):

```
import psutil, json, wmi

from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')

def get_cpu_temperature():
    # Some code here
    return temp

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/get_data")
def get_data():
    temperature = get_cpu_temperature()
    data = {
        'temp_cpu': temperature if temperature is not None else 'N/A',
        'cpu_percent': psutil.cpu_percent(),
        'ram_percent': psutil.virtual_memory().percent,
        'drive_percent': psutil.disk_usage('/').percent
    }
    return json.dumps(data)
```

In case it's needed, this is what i get in `127.0.0.1/get_data`:

`{"temp_cpu": 53.8, "cpu_percent": 0.0, "ram_percent": 43.3, "drive_percent": 85.7}`

**base.html**, here is where I load **uPlot**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/base.css') }}">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/uPlot.iife.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/uPlot.iife.min.js') }}"></script>

</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**, for the example I'm only showing one of the elements to plot:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Metrics {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/index.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/uPlot.min.css') }}">
    </head>
    <header>
        <h1> Computer real time metrics </h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="ram-container">
            <div class="container-title"> <h2> RAM </h2> </div>
            <div class="container-chart" id="ram-chart">
                <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/script_ram.js') }}"></script>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

In the `index.htm` I add the stylesheet of my html and the stylsheet of uPlot, so that the chart is well shown.

Finally, this is the script where I create the charts and try ploting the data:

```
var ramData = [];
var ramTimeStamp = [];
var ramPercentData = [];
var ramChart;

function initializeRAMChart() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('ram-chart');
    ramChart = new uPlot({
        // title: "RAM (%)",
        id: "ram-chart",
        width: 800,
        height: 300,
        cursor: {
            drag: {
                setScale: false,
            }
        },
        select: {
            show: false,
        },
        scales: {
            // x: { time: true, timeUnit: 'ms', timeMin: Date.now() - 60 * 1000 },1704885401336
            x: { time: true, timeUnit: 'ms'},
            y: { range: [0, 100] },
        },
        series: [
            {
                // Initial toggled state
                show: true,
                spanGaps: false,

                // In-legend display
                label: 'RAM Usage (%)',
                value: (_, rawValue) => rawValue,

                // Series style
                points: { show: true, size:4, opacity:1 },
            }
        ],
        axes: [
            { // X
                show: true,
                label: "Time (s)",
                labelSize: 30,
                gap: 5,
                stroke: "white",
                grid: {
                    show: true,
                    stroke: "#eee",
                    width: 0.5,
                    dash: [],
                },
            },
            { // Y
                show: true,
                label: "Percentage (%)",
                labelSize: 30,
                gap: 5,
                stroke: "white",
                grid: {
                    show: true,
                    stroke: "#eee",
                    width: 0.5,
                    dash: [],
                },
            }, 
        ],
    }, ramData, ctx);
}

function updateRAMData() {        
    $.get('/get_data', function (data) {
        try {  
            const parseData = JSON.parse(data);
            const ramPercent = parseData.ram_percent;
            const timestamp = Date.now();

            ramPercentData.push(ramPercent);
            ramTimeStamp.push(timestamp);
            
            ramData = [
                ramTimeStamp.slice(),
                ramPercentData.slice()
            ];

            if (ramData.length > 450) {
                ramData[0].shift();
                ramData[1].shift();
            }

            if (ramData[0].length !== ramData[1].length) {
                console.error("Error: Not same length.");
            }

            console.log('ramData: ', ramData);
            ramChart.setData(ramData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error RAM', error);
        }
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    initializeRAMChart();
    updateRAMData();                        
    setInterval(updateRAMData, 2000);
});
```

Here is what the script above does:

- First of all the plot is created (`ram-chart`).
- Next, `updateRAMData` function. Here we first parse the json data and save it in two different arrays (this si done due to the format uPlot needs for it's data, shown bellow). At the end I plot the data with `ramChart.setData(ramData)`.
- Finally, set an update intervall every 2 seconds.

Data format, by [uPlot](https://github.com/leeoniya/uPlot/tree/master/docs):

```
let data = [
  [1546300800, 1546387200],    // x-values (timestamps)
  [        35,         71],    // y-values (series 1)
  [        90,         15],    // y-values (series 2)
];
```

So, as we can see in the example inside data we have different arrays, one contains the x values (in our case the timestamp) and then we can add different series, we will only add one.

Once the code has been explained, we will see what we obtain. So far I've achived to show the charts:
[image: uPlot charts]

Here is a picture of just, the ram chart. The x axis is set as time but the satrt of the axis is extrange.
[image: ram chart]

The problem is that the points don't appear in the charts. Here I add the console log of the navigator:

```
ramData:  
Array [ (1) […], (1) […] ]
0: Array [ 1705059234112 ]
0: 1705059234112
length: 1
<prototype>: Array []
1: Array [ 43.8 ]
0: 43.8
length: 1
<prototype>: Array []
length: 2
<prototype>: Array []
script_ram.js:126:21
```

```
ramData:  
Array [ (2) […], (2) […] ]
0: Array [ 1705059234112, 1705059236074 ]
0: 1705059234112
1: 1705059236074
length: 2
<prototype>: Array []
1: Array [ 43.8, 43.8 ]
0: 43.8
1: 43.8
length: 2
<prototype>: Array []
length: 2
<prototype>: Array []
script_ram.js:126:21
```

Here I add a picture of the log. [image]

As you can see I get no error, the data is saved as it has to but the points do not appear on the chart. What is wrong with my code?